# landscape client registration

Tags: landscape

looking for some guidance for landscape client config. I just rebuilt LDS server and re-registered clients. One client keeps sending authorization requests even after I accepted it. I tried restarting client, rejecting duplicates - does not work. I compared client config with other client - all the same. Has anyone seen this behavior before? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fully unregister and re-register.

```
sudo apt-get uninstall landscape-client
sudo mv /var/lib/landscape /var/lib/landscape.old
# Remove any duplicate computer in LDS UI
sudo apt-get install landscape-client
# attempt to re-register anew.
```

I know you have probably done something similar, but the /var/lib/landscape part you may have not known about.

Comment: Hi dpb! Thank you for your comment, it did help. BTW, I did this procedure but did not rename '/var/lib/landscape' folder, I guess it was the key! Thanks again and have a good weekend, joe